# How to create local notifications from Start Time till End Time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, localnotification

I've been trying to create certain amount of scheduled notifications that show up at certain hour of the day. I created one notification, calculate the number of notifications from Start Time to End Time and using a for loop I created that amount of notifications, both the Start Time and End Time are given by the user via a UIPicker. The thing is... for some reason not all of the notifications are being granted permission. I have no idea what is going on and how to fix it. Here's my code.

```
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

struct NotificationManager{
    
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    func createNotification(startHour : Int, startMins : Int){
        
        //Ask user for permission
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if granted == true{
                //User granted permission
                print("granted")
                
            } else {
                //Not granted
                print("not granted")
            }
            
            if let err = error {
                //error handling
                print(err)
            }
        }
        
        //Create notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Notification!"
        content.body = "This is a notification"
        
        //Create notification trigger (Initial notification trigger)
        var startDate = DateComponents()
        startDate.calendar = Calendar.current
        startDate.hour = startHour
        startDate.minute = startMins
        
        print("date comps = \(startDate)")
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: startDate, repeats: true)

        //Create notification request
        let initialuuidString = UUID().uuidString
        let initialRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: initialuuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        //Schedule the request with the notification center (Initial notification)
        center.add(initialRequest) { error in
            if let err = error {
                //Handle any errors
                print(err)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeNotifications(){
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    }
    
    func numberOfNotifications(startHour: Int, startMinute: Int, endHour: Int, endMinute: Int, frequency: Int){
        
        //removeNotifications()
        
        var activeHours = 0
    
        if endHour < startHour {
            activeHours = abs(abs(endHour - startHour) - K.Hours.HOURS_IN_DAY)
        } else {
            activeHours = abs(endHour - startHour)
        }
        
        print("active hours = \(activeHours)")
        
        var numberOfNotifications = (activeHours / frequency)
        if numberOfNotifications == 0 {
            numberOfNotifications = 1
        }
        print("number of notifications = \(numberOfNotifications)")

        //Create notifications
        for num in 1...numberOfNotifications {
            let hour = startHour + frequency * num
            createNotification(startHour: hour, startMins: startMinute)
        }
    }
}
```

I get tons of "Not granted" printed out.

[image: Print Statements]

Comment: Just wondering why are you asking for permission on every iteration and don't do anything in it's callback?

Comment: You need first `requestAuthorization`  after you get a response from the user answer `(granted or not granted)` you can register your notifications. There is no point to register notifications without permission and of course they are not even registrated.

Comment: Using a device I gave permission everytime, but just the access gets granted only sometimes and it appears to be random

Comment: You are asking permission each iteration but then you go ahead and try and schedule all the notifications straight away.  You need to 1. Check if you need to ask permission, 2. Ask once. 3. When you get permission then start scheduling notifications.  There will be some time between 2 and 3 because the user has to respond to the request.